# uploading audio files using ajax and php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm recording a voice using html5 and that audio is saved in a BLOB . Then i'm using that blod to upload the audio file into a folder using ajax.but this is not happening.there is my code if someone can help please:

```
 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var li = document.createElement('li');
var au = document.createElement('audio');
var hf = document.createElement('a');

au.controls = true;
au.src = url;
hf.href = url;
hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
li.appendChild(au);
li.appendChild(hf);

var fileName=hf.download;
alert (fileName);
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',             
    data:{"fileName":fileName},
    success: function(response) {      
         console.log("file uploaded");
         console.log(response.fileName);
           } //end of success

    });//end of  ajax
```

the upload folder should contain the audio recordings and yet nothing is saved in the folder.what's going wrong with my code??

server-side:

```
<?php

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$fileName=$_POST['fileName'];

if ($_FILES["fileName"]["error"] > 0) {
console.log( "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileName"]["error"] . "<br>");
} else {


if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"])) {
  console.log( $_FILES["fileName"]["name"] . " already exists. ");
} else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);

}
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where is the server side script? You can't send files with AJAX that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont think it will helpful i have a 500 line code HTML besides js.It's a huge project and missing this part only